# Calling a function in python doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have created two functions. one is called possibles_compile() and the other is called ref_check(). I have defined both of them, but when it comes time to call the function possibles_compile(), it refuses to call the function, and doesn't print the list named possibles like I told it to do afterwards. The code works on its own, but when put into a function and called it doesn't execute. Here are all the relevant code:

```
import random
file = open('Script.txt', 'r')
library = list(file.read().split())
library_length = len(library)
start_words = []
possibles = []
reference = []
total_gen = []
final = ""

for i in range(library_length):
    if '.' in library[i - 1]:
        start_words.append(library[i])
        start_length = len(start_words)

x = random.randint(0, start_length - 1)
print(x)
reference.append(start_words[x])
ref_length = len(reference)
print(reference)
print(ref_length)

def possibles_compile():
    compile = 'yes'
    while compile != 'no':
        if ref_length == 1:
            for i in range(library_length):
                if library[i] == reference[0]:
                    possibles.append(library[i + 1])
                    possibles_length = len(possibles)
        elif ref_length == 2:
            for i in range(library_length):
                if library[i] == reference[0]:
                    if library[i + 1] == reference[1]:
                        possibles.append(library[i + 2])
                        possibles_length = len(possibles)
        elif ref_length == 3:
            for i in range(library_length):
                if library[i] == reference[0]:
                    if library[i + 1] == reference[1]:
                        if library[i + 2] == reference[2]:
                            possibles.append(library[i + 3])
                            possibles_length = len(possibles)
            compile = 'no'

def ref_check():
    index = random.randint(0, possibles_length - 1)
    if ref_length < 4:
        reference.append(possibles[index])
    elif ref_length == 4:
        total_gen.append(reference[0])
        reference[0] = reference[1]
        reference[1] = reference[2]
        reference[2] = reference[3]
        reference[3] = possibles[index]

possibles_compile()
print(possibles)
```

I apologize if you didn't need all of it, but I am very confused and don't know what is going wrong, or why the function not being called prevents the print command from going through.

Comment: Please include the stack trace you get when running `possibles_compile`

Comment: Where does `ref_length` come from?  Its definition isn't included in your code, but your code _uses_ it.

Comment: @SeanVieira similarly `possibles`. I assume that parts of the code is elided here, but that's why they should have included a stack trace, eh? :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So what I'm thinking at a glance, is that "possibles" doesn't have a value in it, unless this is a variable you defined before. My thoughts are:

1. Your possibles_compile() function should return the value you want completed. Outside the function you define your variable and set it to be equal to that return value. So:

   possibles = compile_possibles()

Then whatever you want to be printed would be returned at the end of the function. Like this:

```
return result
```

Then the possibles variable defined outside of the function would be set to the value of "result", which is just an arbitrary variable name I made up for this. Then you just print it.

OR

2. You define possibles and then pass it to your compile_possibles() function as an argument, which means it would become:

   def compile_possibles(possibles):

Then your possibles variable would be modified within the function and you should be able to print it and get the desired result. Let me know if either of these work for you.

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't see the top of your post where you did define possibles. I would still stick with my earlier suggestions of just saying possibles = compile_possibles(), then define a list in the function that you want to return and set to the possibles variable.

If you're working with classes and it's just not in the code here, you might have to reference your classes and variables using self, so self.possibles.append(), or self.compile_possibles()

Comment: I tried doing both options, but neither yielded a result I could use for what I needed them for. I made 'possibles' a list instead of a variable then added a return statement at the end of the possibles_compile function. Option 2 worked the best, but it possibles could only store one item and I needed it to store multiple. Thank you for helping!

Comment: So what I would do is define a list variable in the function itself, like result_list, then return the result_result list. If you're wanting to define possibles before setting its value, you can do:

possibles = None

Then go from there.

Answer (score 1):

You want to edit global variabe named "possibles" in a function. 
Write this:

```
global possibles
```

In main code & in the function "compile_possibles"

This should be working well